# TFS banching strategy and continous integration

Tags: tfs

Ive got a build server setup but am looking at what kind of branching to setup in TFS.  Im going to have 3 different environments - Dev/Test/Prod

As of now, Im looking at a structure like mentioned in [**this**](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Installing+and+Configuring+the+TeamCity+Server) article.  Which is more or less like this:

```
| Main 
  |___Dev branch
  |___Release branch
```

The problem with this approach is that if I want to get everything in the main line, it will bring down everything in the dev & release branch as well?  Should I create a separate "main" branch, so I dont have to pull down everything if I want to us whats in the main line for building to my "Test" environment?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your second thought is better IMO, That way you have to merge Dev to Main and then Merge Main to Prod.   Now main and dev can move forward and you have a snapshot of whats out on the server in PROD which is what you want.

Also from the jobs I've had, this conversation will happen about every 9 months, there is no "Best" solution you just have to do what works.